# Ionic - Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3

Tags: ionic2

I'm trying to build my Ionic project and deploy it to my device, however every time I do I'm getting the following error message

`
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.
>        Required by:
>            project :
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3/gradle-3.3.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3/gradle-3.3.pom'.
>   Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/159.122.18.156] failed: Connection timed out: connect
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.
>   Could not get resource 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3/gradle-3.3.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3/gradle-3.3.pom'.
>   Connect to maven.google.com:443 [maven.google.com/216.58.204.14] failed: Connection timed out: connect`

I can confirm that I've installed Gradle and that it's on the PATH

`gradle -v
Gradle 3.3
Build time:   2017-01-03 15:31:04 UTC
Revision:     075893a3d0798c0c1f322899b41ceca82e4e134b
Groovy:       2.4.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_131 (Oracle Corporation 25.131-b11)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64`

And I have the following in *build.gradle* file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3'
}



allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral();
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

But it still fails to build - any ideas here? I've also tried changing the `mavenCentral()` function to a `maven = { url: 'http://maven.google.com' }` object, but that doesn't work neither.

ben